# Spring Security Basic Auth not using CustomUserDetailsService

Tags: spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

my project is in newest Spring Boot + Jersey and I have a problem with login validation.

My security config is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
@Autowired
private DataSource datasource;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/user/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated().and().httpBasic();

}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
{
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService()).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(datasource);
}

@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService()
{
    return new CustomUserDetailsService(datasource);
}
}
```

but when I do this:

```
@POST
@Path("authenticate")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response authenticate(@HeaderParam("username") String username, @HeaderParam("password") String password)
{
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken =
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
    Authentication authentication = this.authManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

    UserDetails userDetails = this.userService.loadUserByUsername(username);

    return createOkResponse(userDetails.getUsername());
}
```

**authenticate method is using inside InMemoryUserDetailsManager not CustomUserDetailsService which I need for login validation.**
How do I change that?

if needed:

```
public class CustomUserDetailsService extends JdbcUserDetailsManager implements UserDetailsService
{
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

public CustomUserDetailsService(DataSource datasource)
{
    setDataSource(datasource);
}

@Override
public CurrentUserInfo loadUserByUsername(String email)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException
{

    User user = userRepository.findByPrimaryEmailAndEnabledTrue(email);
    handleUserNotFound(email, user);

    return new CurrentUserInfo(user);
}

private void handleUserNotFound(String email, User user)
{
    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user found with email: " + email);
    }
}
}
```

Starter dependencies:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
    exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
}
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey"
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator") { exclude module: 'hsqldb' }
```

Comment: Because you aren't using it. The line `auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(datasource);` effectively disables the line above that, rendering your configuration useless. Also if you are using Spring boot you can remove the `@EnableWebSecurity` as that is already done by Spring Boot.

Comment: Thx Deinum but even with your suggestion it still doens't trigget the loadUserByUsername method in CustomUserDetailsService.

Comment: You are using JAX-RS so make sure that that integration is correctly setup and what is the URL of the service you are calling. You also might want to add `@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)` to your configuration class.

Comment: I'm using spring-boot-starter-jersey package with no other configuration. 
URL is http://localhost:8888/api/user/authenticate and with order it still doesn't want to hit the CustomUserDetailsService...

Comment: Which dependencies (starters) do you have in your dependency list.

Comment: Rename your `configure` method for the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` to something else `configureGlobal` or something, make it `public` and remove the `override`.

Comment: No effect. That method isn't used anywhere then, why doing that? Added dependencies in original post.

Comment: Yes it is it will configure a global authentication manager as opposed to a local one for only your `/api` URIs. You have to put `@Autowired` on that method (forgot that one).

Comment: Wohoo great success :) It works! Can you write it as an answer so I can accept it? Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are "registering" a `AuthenticationManager` only usable for the `/api` URIs and it isn't exposed as a bean to the `ApplicationContext`. When using Spring Boot that will add a global one and inject a default user with a generated password in it.

Spring Boot autoconfig will detect the presence of an already availabe `AuthenticationManager`. To register a global one just create a method which takes a `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` as an argument and annotate if with `@Autowired`. Just make sure it isn't named `configure` as that will not work.

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService()).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(datasource);
}
```